# Hibernate selecting all rows of a table (using .* ) join with multiple tables, giving Exception

Tags: hibernate, join

Is possible with Hibernate do this?

```sql
select A.something, B.something, C.something, D.something , E.*  
      from  A  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.id = B.id_fk  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.id = C.id_fk  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN D ON C.id = D.id_fk  
      LEFT OUTER JOIN E ON A.abc = E.abc;
```

This query works fine in SQL but gives below Exception in Hibernate:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you don't need the "*". hibernate is turning objects , * is meaningless as its for pointing the columns in SQL. When you want the E , it turns the E object.

> SELECT E FROM E

this is the HQL for `SELECT * FROM E`

even "FROM E" works , when you're calling session.createQuery() .

Comment: i understand that, but i also need to select other columns from other tables as well as mentioned in the question:  
select A.something, B.something, C.something, D.something , E.*

Comment: you cannot select columns , you can only select attributes defined in the entity class of your object

Comment: i totally agree with what you are saying. Please let me know if it is posible to retrieve few attributes from diffrent table and all attributes from a single table, all this using a single HQL query. Meaning is it possible to achieve what my SQL query does in my mentioned question? Do you mean to say I should write as below:
select A.something, B.something, C.something, D.something , E
from A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B on A.id = B.id_fk
LEFT OUTER JOIN C ON B.id = C.id_fk
LEFT OUTER JOIN D ON C.id = D.id_fk
LEFT OUTER JOIN E ON A.abc = E.abc; 
This new query is not giving exception but gives NULL for E

Comment: i say , in your hql in your question , replace "E" with "E.*"

Comment: replacing "E" with "E.*" gives below Exception in Hibernate:
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting IDENT, found '*' near line 1

Comment: sorry i was meaning "E.*" with "E"

Comment: hey, i already said that i tried using "E" but it gives NULL for E.

Answer (score 0):

Query in HQL is differ - 
SQL --

> Select * from A ;

HQL --

> from A

SQL --

> select b,c ,d from A

HQL --

> select b,c,d from A

```
org.hibernate.Query query = createQuery("select b FROM aaaa");
        query.setReadOnly(true);
        return (List<Vector<aaaa>>)query.list();
```

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html