# JPA: Pass default parameter into findAll() method

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have several entities and jpa repositories to them. It looks like:

Event:

```
public class Event{ 
@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String description;
}
```

Place:

public class Place{

```
@Column
private String name;

@Column
private String description;

@Column
private Double lon;


@Column
private Double lat;
}
```

And repositories to them:

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Event> {
}

public interface PlaceRepository extends JpaRepository<Place, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Place> {

}
```

It work well. But then I added one else field in each entity calls `tenantId`

Event:

```
    public class Event{ 

    @Column
    private String tenantId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;
    }
```

Place:

```
public class Place{ 

    @Column
    private String tenantId;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private Double lon;


    @Column
    private Double lat;
    }
```

But all my service works with method `findAll()`. So, the question is:
How can I get from "old" method `findAll()` entities only with tenantId = "1" or "2", doesnt matter? It should be work like `findAllByTenantId(String tenantId)` but it should be 'findAll()'. Can I inject somehow into 'findAll()' tenantId params?

Thx.

Comment: Well, if you don't want **all** the records, then it is not a `findAll`, is it? You should build a JPQL query for that with a suitable `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Java generics for JPA findAll() query with WHERE clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24572092/using-java-generics-for-jpa-findall-query-with-where-clause)

Comment: Is it really only `findAll` method?

Comment: So, the goal is how to force `findAll()` to work as a `findAllByTenantId()` not to owerride findAll()?

Comment: In that case, you can add an aspect for `findAll` mthod in which you use your own implementation.

Comment: what is the point of all of the @Column? Make no sense.

Comment: Thanks to @DraganBozanovic for the solution. In fact yes, we can do this via aspects.

Comment: @BillyFrost yes, but it isn`t a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to override the implementation :

```
public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Event> {
    List<Event> findAll(String tenantId);  // findAllByTenantId
}
```

**JPA criteria API translates into the following query:**

```
select e from Event e where e.tenantId = ?1
```

**And**

```
public interface PlaceRepository extends JpaRepository<Place, String>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Place> {
    List<Place> findAll(String tenantId);   // findAllByTenantId
}
```

**JPA criteria API translates into the following query:**

```
select p from Place p where p.tenantId = ?1
```