# Hibernate - Select all rows in a table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Im trying to get my query to load all rows in a table, im working with hibernate.

```
@Override
public List<Teacher> getTeachersBySubject(Subject subject) {
    List<Teacher> teachersBySubject =  entityManager.createQuery("SELECT * FROM teacher t INNER JOIN teacher_subject ts on t.email = ts.email")
            .getResultList();

    return teachersBySubject;
}
```

The * (All) Gives the error im dealing with, it won't load because of hibernate

the error that im getting is this : `org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 8 [SELECT * FROM com.scalda.vos.models.Teacher t INNER JOIN teacher_subject ts on t.email = ts.email]`

Comment: Don't use '*' in HQL query. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10041134/hibernate-selecting-all-rows-of-a-table-using-join-with-multiple-tables-g

Comment: Instead of trying to write quesry in SQL, i'd suggest you to write using HQL (Hibernate Specific Language) AFAIK, you can ommit "SELECT *" part and write "From teacher t ... " and etc. Hibernate will understand what you want and interprete how he needs. See tutorial here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_query_language.htm

Comment: entityManager.createNativeQuery("SELECT t FROM teacher t INNER JOIN teacher_subject ts on t.email = ts.email").getResultList();

Comment: I recommend you using `Criteria` and `meta-model` to make your query more generic.

Answer (score 0):

You have written a native query, which must be compiled using the `createNativeQuery` method.

The `createQuery` expects HQL and not native SQL, and therefore to do it in HQL use just "teacher FROM Teacher". Also, if you are just retrieving a Teacher and not a Teacher-Subject hybrid then, Hibernate can also help you with retrieving associations check [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/associations.html)

Answer (score 0):

its not native and your writing hql so replace * with t.

Comment: When i luse this, i get: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 't' in 'field list' so this doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

as my recommendation, use hql for clear code in hibernate or using `criteria`
but, still running well in native.
For native SQL, use `createSqlQuery`, like :

```
List<Teacher> teachersBySubject =  entityManager.createSqlQuery("SELECT * FROM teacher t INNER JOIN teacher_subject ts on t.email = ts.email")
            .getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

HIbernate expects you to use JPQL, it looks like SQL, but should be like this:

```
SELECT t FROM teacher t JOIN t.subject
```

Of course, it depends on how you Teacher class is annotated (ManyToMany, OneToMany mappings).